# Showing multiple AngularJS routes at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have built an AngularJS single page app to display reports.  There is a select box for the user to select a report from dozens of reports and that report loads in the ui-view using Angular's UI-Router.  If they selected the Big Report, the url is something like myapp.com/#/reports/big-report.

I would like to build a print function that would allow them to select multiple reports from a list and print off just those reports all together.  I was thinking about loading them into a hidden div with print styles to show them when printing.  That seems to work fine for a single report, but I'm not sure how to load multiple.

How would you load multiple "routes" or reports at once into hidden divs?  Trying to think of a way to create a dynamic number of hidden ui-views, but I'm not sure that's correct.  Maybe iframes loading each report route in it, but that seems dirty.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could create a new route that will get each ID (if these reports contain an ID) and render it in the view.
the url would be something like `myapp.com/#/reports/more/1,4,6,8` or any other formatting.
And then you can use AngularJS `$routeParams` to get the reports ID and finally in the view load each of these reports.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a route like /#/reports/print that I could pass the report IDs to as $routeParams or $stateParams.  So I have a PrintReportsController in Angular that has the IDs for all the reports to print, but I'm not sure how to generate those reports.  The only way they currently generate is to call the route specific to that report which calls the Angular controller specific to that report type.  I'm trying to figure out how I can use those existing report controllers and views to generate multiple reports at once.  I hope that makes sense.